# Cruise Control fails but web site still works - The network path was not found

Tags: networking, path, cruisecontrol

We keep receiving this exception on Cruise Control, and it says the build failed, yet the site still functions.  It seems benign, and specific to SVN and Cruise Control (and not the website code), but it would be nice to resolve this issue.  If anyone has run into this, please share your knowledge.

Note: The Windows notification says the build was successful.  When I hover over the "CC" system tray icon, it says "all builds are good".  But the report in the ViewProjectReport.aspx page in the Cruise Control Dashboard says "Failed"

Nobody is committing code to SVN when these builds take place.  So I also don't know what is triggering them.

```
2011-08-29 13:48:44 (Failed)
2011-08-29 13:47:32 (Failed)
2011-08-29 13:46:11 (Failed)
2011-08-28 06:24:52 (Failed)
2011-08-26 08:46:04 (Failed)
2011-08-24 20:30:41 (Failed)
2011-08-24 20:29:19 (Failed)
2011-08-24 20:27:57 (Failed)
2011-08-22 22:59:22 (Failed)
2011-08-22 22:58:10 (Failed)





BUILD EXCEPTION



Error Message:
System.IO.IOException: The network path was not found.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, DirectorySecurity dirSecurity)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path, DirectorySecurity directorySecurity)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.NewProcessInfo(String args, IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.NewHistoryProcessInfo(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to, String url)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModificationsWithLogging(ISourceControl sc, IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request) 


 Project:

LIMS



Date of build:

2011-08-29 13:48:44



Running time:

00:00:10



Integration Request:

Build (IfModificationExists) triggered from IntervalTrigger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your error is coming from an [`IntervalTrigger`](http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/Interval%20Trigger.html).

> The trigger ... force a build even if no changes have occurred to source control.

Do any exist? Suspect that you've got one defined, and the drop path can't be found.

```
<project name="Project 1" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">

  <triggers>
    <!--yourFirstTriggerType .. -->
    <!--yourOtherTriggerType .. -->
  </triggers>
```

Comment: @Mr. they're under the `project` element.